# Add value in an entity from context variables or backend in Watson assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I need to add a user input as an entity value, I don't know if I can do it from the backend, dialog, or context variables.

For example:
I have an entity called colors, which only has red and blue.
Within a dialog I ask him what color he likes, if he says one of the ones that I already have in the entity, nothing happens, but if he says one that he does not have, I must add the value to the entity.
It can be from the API or from the Watson assistant console.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Add more details. Do you want to automatically extend entitiy definitions based on user input or do you want WA to learn from user input? Provide some examples, so that it can be understood. And what have you tried or read so far?

Comment: I have an entity called colors, which only has red and blue.
Within a dialog I ask him what color he likes, if he says one of the ones that I already have in the entity, nothing happens, but if he says one that he does not have, I must add the value to the entity.

Comment: That's incorrect use of entities. What you are looking for are context variables. They can hold such values. An entity would be "colors" and you start with red, green, blue, black, white and WA would learn other colors on the way, on its own. That's called AI... :)

Comment: In this case I really don't know how Watson's AI works, because unless you add an entity or a training phrase, it will never learn it on its own.

Comment: Are you trying to teach WA values for a specific user or in general? Do you want WA to recognize colors?